# File Server Folder Permissions on Windows Server 2012 w/Domain

Tags: windows, server, active-directory, ntfs, fileserver

I am migrating an old File Server to a new one and have created a new structure that will have ranging permissions.

The new file structure is similar to :

**01 - CEO   ........ <- only CEO can access 

02 - Finance ........ <- only Finance & CEO can access 

03 - HR ..............       <- only HR can access 

04 - Operations .......   <- Everyone can access but some sub-folder restrictions as well**

How do i set permissions on these folders so that everyone can see the folders, but if anyone except the CEO trying to access the 01-CEO folder, they get access denied?  Obviously, any sub-folders will never been seen by anyone except the CEO.

I have tried ways of permissions, but for the life of me cannot get this to happen.   I have been able to make the 01-CEO folder disappears for non-CEO's but I'd prefer an "access denied" message so that people know the folder exists.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Needed to disable Access-Based Enumeration in the Server Manager.